# sql queries side by side

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have a database of reviews, and I want to see how many have the word love and how many have the word hate in them. Easy peasy, right:

```
Select * from 
(select count(*) from review where text like '%love%' ) as loves,
(select count(*) from review where text like '%hate%') as hates
```

The problem is that the column names in the query result are both 'count(*)', and I can't seem to figure out how to fix that (I am new to SQL, so this is probably trivial). I am using `sqlite`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need subqueries for that:

```
select sum(text like '%love%') as loves,
       sum(text like '%hate%') as hates
from review
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5ecb8/1)

Comment: Cool! This uses the fact that the condition returns 1/0 for true/false - is this universal, or just sqlite?

Comment: But you can generally use `sum(case when text like '%love%' then 1 else 0 end)` which should work for all SQL engines.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct. But you'd want to use alias names for the columns so as to distinguish the two counts. Moreover, comma-separated joins have been made redundant in Standard SQL in 1992. Use explicit joins instead, in your case a `CROSS JOIN`.

```
select * 
from (select count(*) as love_count from review where text like '%love%' ) as loves
cross join (select count(*) as hate_count from review where text like '%hate%') as hates;
```

Comment: Cool! What do you mean by "made redundant"? Does it mean that they will not work, or that they are just viewed as poor style?

Comment: They are considered poor style. We use `[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` instead today.